# ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have installed homebrew, and from homebrew I installed pyqt5. I am also using the latest version of python on my PC. But my application is not working. Whenever I am importing any pyqt5 module it is giving me an ImportError. Can some please help me.

**Below is the error:**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the wrong python binary on your system.

If you've installed the Qt5 bindings for Python (`brew install pyqt@5`), then the easiest way to use them is to create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) that uses *your system-site-packages*.

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv --system-site-packages venv
```

This issue might be complicated by the possibility of homebrew-installed python, or shims provided by something like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv): you should be able to use any of them with this virtualenv approach, but using `/usr/bin/python3` allows you to explicitly use macOS's default python build.

---

Note for Mac M1 (ARM):

If you're running on an M1 chip (although this question may be too old for that), the [PyPI PyQt5 module](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#files) does not currently have an ARM build. The above approach will work on M1 macs, but if you find a requirements.txt file that uses `pyqt`, you can install and use it via Rosetta:

```
arch -arch x86_64 /usr/bin/python3 -m venv venv
# use up-to-date pip, and install pyqt's builder first
arch -arch x86_64 venv/bin/pip install -U pip pyqt5-sip
arch -arch x86_64 venv/bin/pip install pyqt
```